# Execute List of Single sequentially with dependency in RxJava2

Tags: java, reactive-programming, rx-java2

I have a List of Single with same object, for example:

```java
//getter and setter are omitted
public class MyObject {
    private String a;
    private String b;
    private String c;
.
.
.
}

public Single<MyObject> methodA (MyObject o) {
    return Single.fromCallable(() -> {
        MyObject result;
        if (Objects.nonNull(o)) {
            result = (MyObject) o.clone();
        } else {
            result = new MyObject();
        }
        result.setA("a");
        return result;
    });
}
//similar to B and C
```

Then the way to concat this is:

```java
Single<MyObject> result = Single.just(new MyObject())
                                .flatMap(x -> methodA(x))
                                .flatMap(x -> methodB(x));
```

But if I have another method or maybe a `List<Single<MyObject>>`, I need to write all of them one by one.

Are there a way to execute this? maybe concat but the result of first single is not a parameter to second single.

Comment: What do you mean? Setting every field `a`..`z` to `"a"`? Reflection maybe? `Map<String, String>` as a field?

Comment: @akanokd For example, there is a method to modify MyObject but I need to execute methodA, then get the result and execute methodB get the result and execute the new method, maybe execute all of method without using flatmap and write all of them one by one

Comment: Do you mean, do those methodA, methodB, methodC calls, but then for each individual MyObject from those Singles?

Comment: Yes, and I need a MyObject that pass for all methods.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to unroll the list and do `concatMapSingle`:

```
List<Single<MyObject>> source = ...

Flowable.fromIterable(source)
    .concatMapSingle(obj -> Single.just(obj)
                                .flatMap(x -> methodA(x))
                                .flatMap(x -> methodB(x))
    )
```